# How do I rename an attribute code in Magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.4, entity-attribute-value

I want to rename an existing attribute's code to something else. The reason is because the attribute field is filled out for 300+ products and I don't want to have to re-import all of those just because I changed the code of an attribute.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can edit it in mysql at `eav_attribute.attribute_code`.  Be sure to take backups prior and re-index all in `System>Index Management` afterwards.

Answer (score 31):

It is much easier to use an upgrade script with the following content for that:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'old_attribute_code', array('attribute_code' => 'new_attribute_code'));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have access to the database, you can run this SQL command

```
UPDATE eav_attribute
SET   attribute_code = 'your_NEW_attribute_code'
WHERE attribute_code = 'your_OLD_attribute_code'
```

don't forget to re-index and edit your sql codes afterwards

Comment: That's directly in the SQL?

Comment: @user9903 yes it is

Answer (score 2):

> It is much easier to use an upgrade script with the following content
>   for that:
>
> ```
> $installer = $this;
> $installer->startSetup();
> $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'old_attribute_code', array('attribute_code' => 'new_attribute_code'));
> $installer->endSetup();
> ```

Instead of a full install script you can run this also from simple file, just replace

```
$installer = $this;
```

with

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$installer  = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
...
```

Comment: How Do I do this with magento 2

Answer (score 1):

Take inspiration the following script :

```
<?php
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->query("
  UPDATE eav_attribute val
  SET  val.attribute_code = "SET VALUE WHAT YOU WANT"
  WHERE  val.attribute_id = (
     SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
     WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4
       AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
    )
");
```

Comment: Why do you use a subquery to find the `attribute_id` when you already know the existing `attribute_code`?

Comment: How do I do it with magneto 2

Answer (score 0):

After you edit the attribute_code and reindex all you may also find that you need to clear magento caches including Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage -- or alternately `rm -rf var/cache/*` (see below for caveats).

Magento uses caches to store queries referenced by `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);` and possibly other similar calls. Queries like this one:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`[CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]`, `e`.`[CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE]` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.sku = '[SKU]') LIMIT 1
```

More about what Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage do here:
http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/05/21/clearing-the-cache-in-magento/

The important paragraph in the article is this

> This may seem trivial to those of you using the default filesystem cache with Magento. You can just go in and manually “rm -rf var/cache/*” to clear the cache out. But those of you using the alternate cache types (xcache, memcached, apc, db, sqlite), the “Flush Magento Cache” may not be doing what you want it to do. So, when all else fails and you want to be sure the cache is totally clear, be sure to click on “Flush Cache Storage”.
>
> One caveat before I say farewell, if you are using one of the shared storage cache types – for example two different apps using the same memcached instance – clicking on “Flush Cache Storage” might remove the cache entries for that other application as well. This may not be what you want, so just take heed.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on Magento 2.4

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
$customerSetup->updateAttribute(
    Customer::ENTITY,
    'old_attribute_code',
    'attribute_code', // don't change this one
    'new_attribute_code'
);
```